# python で、あるWebアプリを早く作る必要がある時の、お勧めのライブラリの組み合わせはあるでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3

経験者の皆様に、タイトルの事について、識者の皆様の意見を伺わせて頂けないでしょうか。
あれこれ考えたり検証している時間が無く、周りに気軽に聞ける経験者がいないため、投稿させて頂きました。
どうぞ宜しくお願いします。

#### 要件

下記のWebアプリを新しく作りたい。

- できればpythonだけで実現し、JavaScript HTML CSSを使う事は避けたい
- クライアント領域は左右2つに分け、

  - 左にリストボックスやボタン等のウィジェットを付けたい
  - 右に任意の地図画像(png)を描き、その上に点や線も描きたい
    この描画物は、マウスクリックに反応する=ヒットテストを行うようにしたい。
- 長く使う=保守し続ける事になりそう。

#### 私の状況

- Webアプリ作成経験ナシ
- pythonは初心者
- VC++とMFCとDirect3DとOpenGLでWinのGUIツールを作った事はある
- 素早い実装を要求されてる

#### 検証中の事

開発速度を重視し下記を試している。しかし適切といえるか確信できなくなった。

- streamlit
  Webアプリ作成をpythonで行うための基本ライブラリ。
  コード量は少ないが、シバリ・できない事が多い。敷かれたレールの範囲内の処理しかできない。
  例えば、プログラムからリロード=画面再描画ができない。
- plotly
  streamlitと連携し、描画するライブラリ。グラフ描画用で、自由な描画には向かないかも。
- streamlit-drawable-canvas
  https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-drawable-canvas/ のサンプルコードを実行して調べようとした。がpython3.9の環境ではエラーで実行不能だった。

#### 環境

- Python 3.9
- Windows 10 Pro. x64 20H2
- Docker等の仮想環境は未使用

**過去の関連質問:**
[plotly には、自由に点や線や画像を描画する機能はあるでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/77980)

Comment: 「JavaScript HTML CSSを使う事は避けたい」がちょっと厳しいかもしれないですね。Webアプリの設計の自由度をもとめば求めるほどフロントエンドでの拡張度があがり結果的にはそれらの知識をある前提でのライブラリがほとんどになると思います。

Comment: 宣伝文句的には何か良さそうな [PyWebIO](https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) というモジュールがあるようです。HTMLやJavaScriptの知識は不要とあるので、調べてみてはどうでしょう？ こんな紹介記事も。[Create Interactive Web Applications in Pure Python with PyWebIO](https://medium.com/spatial-data-science/create-interactive-web-applications-in-pure-python-with-pywebio-f6a8acc9cf6c) あとは別の商業製品でしょうか、こんな記事があります。[Working with web maps and web scenes - ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-web-maps-and-web-scenes/)

Comment: 自由に描画したい目的と違う(あるいはStreamlit同様に拡張性に難がある)かもしれませんが、`Django`に[GeoDjango](https://homata.gitbook.io/geodjango/geodjango/geodjango)というモジュールがあって、地図とか地理空間情報を扱うのが楽になるようです。付加情報の無い単なるイメージデータだけではなく、実世界の情報とリンクを考えているなら、考慮してみても良いのでは？ [GeoDjangoではじめる地理空間情報](https://homata.gitbook.io/geodjango/hajimeni/readme), [PostGISとGeoDjangoを使って...](https://blog.bitmeister.jp/?tag=geo), [GeoDjangoでWeb地図をつくろう！](https://medium.com/infradatachallenge/idc-river-ce0f6cd3da43), [Djangoで地図アプリ開発をしよう【前編】](https://note.com/shinya_hd/n/n8de567cd82a4), [GeoDjango入門チュートリアル](https://sinyblog.com/django/geodjango-001/)

Comment: 皆様、様々なご意見の投稿に貴重な時間と労力をお割き頂き、誠にありがとうございました。js html css は下記のmetropolis様が提示して下さったように、「自在に設計」するには必須かもしれません。が私は自由度より完成速度が求められています。ので、やはりやや自由度を犠牲にしてもpythonのみで出来る手段を探したいです。PyWebIOという物は初めて知りました。pythonだけでイケるのは心強いです。他にもそれに関する情報のURLのご提示、ありがとうございました。早速調べますね。Djangoはチラホラ聞きました。大雑把な印象は、streamlitの高機能版( コード量が要る分、より多くの細かい希望に応えられる )ライブラリという感じでした。streamlitでどうしても実現不能なら、PyWebIO → Django の順に探っていこうと思います。重ね重ね、皆様どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Bokeh Visualization Library](https://bokeh.org/) を使うのはどうでしょうか。

ただし、

> できればpythonだけで実現し、JavaScript HTML CSSを使う事は避けたい

クリックイベントを検出してコールバックを実行するので `JavaScript` や `CSS` を使用しています。

```py
import os
import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, Button, Div
from bokeh.models.layouts import Spacer
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import Column, Row
from bokeh.io import curdoc

# data view
width, height = 800, 800
num_range = (0, 100)
plot = figure(
  title='東京23区',
  plot_width=width, plot_height=height,
  x_range=num_range, y_range=num_range,
  tools='pan,wheel_zoom,reset', toolbar_location='above',
  active_scroll='wheel_zoom')

# background image
plot.image_url(
  url=['https://livedoor.blogimg.jp/unnyas31-sougou/imgs/8/b/8bcba2f3.gif'],
  x=0, y=0, w=num_range[1], h=num_range[1], anchor='bottom_left')

# draw 20 circles
k = 40
c = random.sample(range(*num_range), k=k)
plot.circle(
  x=c[:k//2], y=c[k//2:], size=15, color='blue', alpha=0.5)

# draw 20 lines
p = random.sample(range(*num_range), k=2*k)
for i in range(0, 2*k, 4):
  plot.line(
    x=p[i:i+2], y=p[i+2:i+4],
    line_width=2, line_color='red', line_alpha=0.5)

# callback on click event
def callback(div):
  return CustomJS(args=dict(div=div), code="""
    var line = "<span>" +
      "x=" + Number(cb_obj.x).toFixed(2) + ", " +
      "y=" + Number(cb_obj.y).toFixed(2) +
      "</span>\\n";
    var text = div.text.concat(line);
    var lines = text.split("\\n")
    if (lines.length > 10) lines.shift();
    div.text = lines.join("\\n");
  """)
click_pos = Div(style={
  'width': '120px', 'height':'170px', 'background': '#E2DCF4',
  'text-align': 'center'
})
plot.js_on_event('tap', callback(click_pos))

# selection box
select = Select(
  title='Option:', value='午前',
  options=['午前', '午後', '深夜'])

# button
button = Button(label='Push me', button_type='success')

# layout     
layout = Row(
  Column(Spacer(height=50), button, select, click_pos, width=100),
  Spacer(width=50),
  plot
)
curdoc().add_root(layout)

os.environ['BOKEH_LOG_LEVEL'] = 'error'
output_file('plot.html')
show(layout)
```

以下は `Bokeh` の `output_file` で出力した HTML+JavaScript ファイルになりますが、地図上のポイントをクリックすると左側の表示領域にその座標が表示されます(最新10ポイント分)。

**plot.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Bokeh Plot</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.3.2.min.js" integrity="sha384-XypntL49z55iwGVUW4qsEu83zKL3XEcz0MjuGOQ9SlaaQ68X/g+k1FcioZi7oQAc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.3.2.min.js" integrity="sha384-TX0gSQTdXTTeScqxj6PVQxTiRW8DOoGVwinyi1D3kxv7wuxQ02XkOxv0xwiypcAH" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Bokeh.set_log_level("error");
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
              <div class="bk-root" id="7765f21b-c784-43ae-9371-9e005d5ffef7" data-root-id="1145"></div>
        <script type="application/json" id="1605">
          {"b1a4274d-e7bb-42ce-ab03-d72628b910ed":{"defs":[],"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1063"},"glyph":{"id":"1064"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1065"},"view":{"id":"1067"}},"id":"1066","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1133"},"glyph":{"id":"1134"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1135"},"view":{"id":"1137"}},"id":"1136","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1063"}},"id":"1067","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"children":[{"id":"1142"},{"id":"1141"},{"id":"1140"},{"id":"1138"}],"width":100},"id":"1143","type":"Column"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1068"}},"id":"1072","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1185","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"args":{"div":{"id":"1138"}},"code":"\n    var line = \"&lt;span&gt;\" +\n      \"x=\" + Number(cb_obj.x).toFixed(2) + \", \" +\n      \"y=\" + Number(cb_obj.y).toFixed(2) +\n      \"&lt;/span&gt;\\n\";\n    var text = div.text.concat(line);\n    var lines = text.split(\"\\n\")\n    if (lines.length &gt; 10) lines.shift();\n    div.text = lines.join(\"\\n\");\n  "},"id":"1139","type":"CustomJS"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1069","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[55,52],"y":[90,16]},"selected":{"id":"1170"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1169"}},"id":"1068","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1133"}},"id":"1137","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"options":["\u5348\u524d","\u5348\u5f8c","\u6df1\u591c"],"title":"Option:","value":"\u5348\u524d"},"id":"1140","type":"Select"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1073"}},"id":"1077","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1074","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"height":50},"id":"1142","type":"Spacer"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[5,51],"y":[10,93]},"selected":{"id":"1172"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1171"}},"id":"1073","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1186","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"button_type":"success","icon":null,"label":"Push me"},"id":"1141","type":"Button"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1068"},"glyph":{"id":"1069"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1070"},"view":{"id":"1072"}},"id":"1071","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1070","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"width":50},"id":"1144","type":"Spacer"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1078"}},"id":"1082","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1079","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[37,88],"y":[23,94]},"selected":{"id":"1174"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1173"}},"id":"1078","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"children":[{"id":"1143"},{"id":"1144"},{"id":"1002"}]},"id":"1145","type":"Row"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"1152"},"major_label_policy":{"id":"1151"},"ticker":{"id":"1018"}},"id":"1017","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1033"},"glyph":{"id":"1034"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1035"},"view":{"id":"1037"}},"id":"1036","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1073"},"glyph":{"id":"1074"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1075"},"view":{"id":"1077"}},"id":"1076","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1075","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1083"}},"id":"1087","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1187","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1084","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"axis":{"id":"1017"},"dimension":1,"ticker":null},"id":"1020","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[30,67],"y":[43,44]},"selected":{"id":"1176"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1175"}},"id":"1083","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1018","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1078"},"glyph":{"id":"1079"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1080"},"view":{"id":"1082"}},"id":"1081","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1043"}},"id":"1047","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1080","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1188","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1022","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1088"}},"id":"1092","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1021","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1089","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1023","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[69,89],"y":[24,84]},"selected":{"id":"1178"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1177"}},"id":"1088","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1083"},"glyph":{"id":"1084"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1085"},"view":{"id":"1087"}},"id":"1086","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1014","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[98,34],"y":[77,66]},"selected":{"id":"1158"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1157"}},"id":"1038","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"text":"\u6771\u4eac23\u533a"},"id":"1003","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"style":{"background":"#E2DCF4","height":"170px","text-align":"center","width":"120px"}},"id":"1138","type":"Div"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1085","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"axis":{"id":"1013"},"ticker":null},"id":"1016","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1093"}},"id":"1097","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1038"},"glyph":{"id":"1039"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1040"},"view":{"id":"1042"}},"id":"1041","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"anchor":"bottom_left","h":{"value":100},"url":{"field":"url"},"w":{"value":100},"x":{"value":0},"y":{"value":0}},"id":"1029","type":"ImageURL"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1094","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"1013"}],"center":[{"id":"1016"},{"id":"1020"}],"height":800,"js_event_callbacks":{"tap":[{"id":"1139"}]},"left":[{"id":"1017"}],"renderers":[{"id":"1031"},{"id":"1036"},{"id":"1041"},{"id":"1046"},{"id":"1051"},{"id":"1056"},{"id":"1061"},{"id":"1066"},{"id":"1071"},{"id":"1076"},{"id":"1081"},{"id":"1086"},{"id":"1091"},{"id":"1096"},{"id":"1101"},{"id":"1106"},{"id":"1111"},{"id":"1116"},{"id":"1121"},{"id":"1126"},{"id":"1131"},{"id":"1136"}],"title":{"id":"1003"},"toolbar":{"id":"1024"},"toolbar_location":"above","width":800,"x_range":{"id":"1005"},"x_scale":{"id":"1009"},"y_range":{"id":"1007"},"y_scale":{"id":"1011"}},"id":"1002","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"blue"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"blue"},"size":{"value":15},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1035","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[53,0],"y":[80,50]},"selected":{"id":"1180"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1179"}},"id":"1093","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1189","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1088"},"glyph":{"id":"1089"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1090"},"view":{"id":"1092"}},"id":"1091","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1039","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1044","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1090","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1059","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1098"}},"id":"1102","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1099","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[41,13],"y":[62,21]},"selected":{"id":"1182"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1181"}},"id":"1098","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1190","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"blue"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.5},"line_color":{"value":"blue"},"size":{"value":15},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1034","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1093"},"glyph":{"id":"1094"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1095"},"view":{"id":"1097"}},"id":"1096","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[56,71],"y":[97,60]},"selected":{"id":"1166"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1165"}},"id":"1058","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1095","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1033"}},"id":"1037","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1103"}},"id":"1107","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1050","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1104","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1048"},"glyph":{"id":"1049"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1050"},"view":{"id":"1052"}},"id":"1051","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[76,33],"y":[18,38]},"selected":{"id":"1184"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1183"}},"id":"1103","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1098"},"glyph":{"id":"1099"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1100"},"view":{"id":"1102"}},"id":"1101","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[79,26],"y":[81,58]},"selected":{"id":"1164"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1163"}},"id":"1053","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[0,78,90,10,15,49,45,17,47,48,69,3,70,98,92,96,35,58,46,56],"y":[79,50,9,34,77,2,40,27,81,8,26,64,43,65,28,32,62,25,24,36]},"selected":{"id":"1156"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1155"}},"id":"1033","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1100","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1108"}},"id":"1112","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1191","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1054","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1109","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1053"}},"id":"1057","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[65,59],"y":[86,63]},"selected":{"id":"1186"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1185"}},"id":"1108","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1148","type":"AllLabels"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1045","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1043"},"glyph":{"id":"1044"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1045"},"view":{"id":"1047"}},"id":"1046","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1103"},"glyph":{"id":"1104"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1105"},"view":{"id":"1107"}},"id":"1106","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"end":100},"id":"1007","type":"Range1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1149","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1105","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1192","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[36,35],"y":[48,78]},"selected":{"id":"1162"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1161"}},"id":"1048","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1113"}},"id":"1117","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1009","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1049","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1114","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1151","type":"AllLabels"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1048"}},"id":"1052","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[40,4],"y":[85,82]},"selected":{"id":"1188"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1187"}},"id":"1113","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1152","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1108"},"glyph":{"id":"1109"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1110"},"view":{"id":"1112"}},"id":"1111","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1110","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1028"}},"id":"1032","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1118"}},"id":"1122","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1028"},"glyph":{"id":"1029"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1030"},"view":{"id":"1032"}},"id":"1031","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1119","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1040","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[39,72],"y":[28,8]},"selected":{"id":"1190"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1189"}},"id":"1118","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1193","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1113"},"glyph":{"id":"1114"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1115"},"view":{"id":"1117"}},"id":"1116","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"anchor":"bottom_left","global_alpha":0.1,"h":{"value":100},"url":{"field":"url"},"w":{"value":100},"x":{"value":0},"y":{"value":0}},"id":"1030","type":"ImageURL"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1115","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1123"}},"id":"1127","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1124","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1038"}},"id":"1042","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[61,46],"y":[27,32]},"selected":{"id":"1192"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1191"}},"id":"1123","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1194","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1118"},"glyph":{"id":"1119"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1120"},"view":{"id":"1122"}},"id":"1121","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[6,83],"y":[11,14]},"selected":{"id":"1160"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1159"}},"id":"1043","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1120","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"1149"},"major_label_policy":{"id":"1148"},"ticker":{"id":"1014"}},"id":"1013","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1128"}},"id":"1132","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1011","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1129","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"active_multi":null,"active_scroll":{"id":"1022"},"tools":[{"id":"1021"},{"id":"1022"},{"id":"1023"}]},"id":"1024","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{"data":{"url":["https://livedoor.blogimg.jp/unnyas31-sougou/imgs/8/b/8bcba2f3.gif"]},"selected":{"id":"1154"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1153"}},"id":"1028","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[73,75],"y":[57,54]},"selected":{"id":"1194"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1193"}},"id":"1128","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1053"},"glyph":{"id":"1054"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1055"},"view":{"id":"1057"}},"id":"1056","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1123"},"glyph":{"id":"1124"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1125"},"view":{"id":"1127"}},"id":"1126","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1055","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1125","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1065","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1195","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1058"}},"id":"1062","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1134","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[1,47],"y":[95,49]},"selected":{"id":"1168"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1167"}},"id":"1063","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"data":{"x":[91,42],"y":[15,22]},"selected":{"id":"1196"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1195"}},"id":"1133","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.5,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1064","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1135","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1128"},"glyph":{"id":"1129"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1130"},"view":{"id":"1132"}},"id":"1131","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1058"},"glyph":{"id":"1059"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1060"},"view":{"id":"1062"}},"id":"1061","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1060","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"red","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1130","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1196","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1173","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"end":100},"id":"1005","type":"Range1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1174","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1163","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1164","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1175","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1153","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1176","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1154","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1165","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1166","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1177","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1155","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1178","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1156","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1167","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1168","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1179","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1157","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1180","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1158","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1169","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1170","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1181","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1159","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1182","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1160","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1171","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1172","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1183","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1161","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1184","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1162","type":"Selection"}],"root_ids":["1145"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"2.3.2"}}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var fn = function() {
              Bokeh.safely(function() {
                (function(root) {
                  function embed_document(root) {
                  var docs_json = document.getElementById('1605').textContent;
                  var render_items = [{"docid":"b1a4274d-e7bb-42ce-ab03-d72628b910ed","root_ids":["1145"],"roots":{"1145":"7765f21b-c784-43ae-9371-9e005d5ffef7"}}];
                  root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
                  }
                  if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                    embed_document(root);
                  } else {
                    var attempts = 0;
                    var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                      if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        embed_document(root);
                      } else {
                        attempts++;
                        if (attempts > 100) {
                          clearInterval(timer);
                          console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
                        }
                      }
                    }, 10, root)
                  }
                })(window);
              });
            };
            if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
            else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
          })();
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: python + js + html + css を使うのですね。pythonコード内にjsをインライン展開する方法がある事は、初めてしりました。もしかしたら、工数・質 をバランス良く解決しようとしたら、最適かもしれませんね。が、今はそれら言語を組み合わせる技量も習得時間も無いため、最後の策にさせて頂こうと思います。又、3種のコードを保守するコストも気になります。  ので、まずは身の丈に合った「何とかpythonだけでWebアプリを作る方法」を考えます。どうもありがとうございました。